# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class Button

Tags: android, android-studio

here im my error sample and my .xml

```
10-22 15:47:02.959 18003-18003/tips.admin.tipsscore.rewards E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: tips.admin.tipsscore.rewards, PID: 18003
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{tips.admin.tipsscore.rewards/tips.admin.tipsscore.rewards.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class Button
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class Button
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
        at tips.admin.tipsscore.rewards.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

XML:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/back"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="12dp" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/rewards"
    android:layout_width="124dp"
    android:layout_height="53dp"
    android:background="@drawable/reward_btn"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="34dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="82dp" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="348dp"
    android:layout_height="428dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/bg_content"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="67dp" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/invite"
    android:layout_width="317dp"
    android:layout_height="79dp"
    android:background="@drawable/reward_btn"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="34dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="290dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/plus"
    android:layout_width="39dp"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:background="@drawable/btnplus"
    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="325dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="210dp"
    android:layout_height="74dp"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/barkoin"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="154dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/coins"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:text="000000"
    android:textColor="#0ede50"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="229dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/availabele"
    android:layout_width="205dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"

    android:text="YOU HAVE 20 AVAILILABE GIFTS "
    android:textColor="#0ede50"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="163dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="67dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/redeam"
    android:layout_width="317dp"
    android:layout_height="79dp"

    android:background="@drawable/reward_btn"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="34dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="396dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/refeer"
    android:layout_width="267dp"
    android:layout_height="99dp"
    android:text="DID YOU KNOW INVITING OR REFERRING YOU FRIENDS CAN EARN YOU MORE COINS? INVITE YOUR FRIENDS FOR MORE COINS "
    android:textColor="#0ede50"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="58dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="187dp" />
```

Comment: That can't be your whole XML.

Comment: Usually this is caused by a large drawable that has been set as background of the button. Remove the background of the button in line 10 of the xml (and the other buttons if the same problem persists but pointing to other lines) and try again.